# How do I establish the base case for a recursive boolean function that checks whether a digit c is part of an integer n?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to write a function that, as mentioned in the title, attempts to return a simple true/false flag depending on whether the digit 'c' is part of an integer 'n' or not. However, much do my dismay, I've been hitting a wall for the past few hours on how to proceed in regards of the base case. My last attempt as shown below, should, according to my latest pen and paper attempt, produce the desired result. It does, however, result in a stack overflow:

```
bool intTest(int n, char c) {
    int nextDigit { 
        n 
    };
    int lastDigit { 
        nextDigit % 10 
    };
    if (c == lastDigit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return intTest(nextDigit / 10, c);
    }
}
```

It is part of a homework assignment (which also forbids any loops in the function) and as such doesn't need an entire solution. Nevertheless I'd still appreciate any pointers or hints in regards to what, I can only assume, is a logic error on my behalf. Thanks!

Comment: if n is 0 you should stop :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: what happens when nextDigit / 10 is *zero*?

In general, all recursion functions need a criterion to know when to stop, that should be always valid (the algorithm should always stop).

The criterion you use here - which is valid: you stop when the last digit is the one you seek - does not come into play if the number does not contain the digit anywhere. So you need also a second criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is missing the "false"-case (if the searched for digit is not part of the integer). This would be the case if you cannot divide n any longer by 10.

```
#include <iostream>

bool intTest(int n, char c) {
    const int lastDigit{ n % 10 };
    if (c == lastDigit)
        return true;
    else
        if ( n < 10 )
            return false;
        else
            return intTest(n / 10, c);
}

auto main() -> int {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << intTest(15, 5) << '\n'; // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << intTest(15, 0) << '\n'; // false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things which should be improved, of differing severity:

1. You don't check for ultimate failure, only for success. Which leads to infinite recursion in that case.
2. The function-name is useless. `hasDigit()` would be much better.
3. Does the number zero have the digit zero? Probably yes, though you could make a case for no. At the moment, all numbers are considered to have that digit.
4. Your function should be marked `constexpr`, because executing at compile-time should be allowed.
5. Your function should be marked `noexcept`, because it cannot throw.
6. You should assert the pre-conditions of public functions, namely that `n` is not negative, and that `c` is a decimal digit.
   Or better yet, use the right datatypes.
7. You might want to allow different bases, whether as non-type template-arguments or as function-arguments.
8. Your code is needlessly complicated. Simplify.

```
constexpr bool hasDigit(unsigned n, unsigned char c) noexcept {
    constexpr unsigned char base = 10;
    assert(c < base);
    return n % base == c || n / base && hasDigit(n / base, c);
}
```